# getting AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: null: null amazon in app purchase fire stick tv

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement amazon's in app purchase(IAP) in my application. I followed the below article to implement it.
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-implement-iap.html

But I am receiving below error when I am calling PurchasingService.purchase(MySku.MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS.getSku());

```
    com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a: AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILURE: null: null
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.b.a(AuthenticationTokenVerifier.java:94)
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:204)
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.a.a.a(AbstractCommandTask.java:131)
        at com.amazon.a.a.n.b.b$1.run(SimpleTaskPipeline.java:179)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

MySku.java

```
public enum MySku {

    //The only subscription product used in this sample app
    MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS("com.subscription.annually", "US");

    private final String sku;
    private final String availableMarkpetplace;

    /**
     * Returns the Sku string of the MySku object
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getSku() {
        return this.sku;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Available Marketplace of the MySku object
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getAvailableMarketplace() {
        return this.availableMarkpetplace;
    }

    private MySku(final String sku, final String availableMarkpetplace) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.availableMarkpetplace = availableMarkpetplace;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the MySku object from the specified Sku and marketplace value.
     *
     * @param sku
     * @param marketplace
     * @return
     */
    public static MySku fromSku(final String sku, final String marketplace) {
        if (MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS.getSku().equals(sku) && (null == marketplace || MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS.getAvailableMarketplace()
                .equals(marketplace))) {
            return MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following code in your Android Manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver" android:exported="true"
          android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action
        android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```